# how to add persistence to ncurses?

Tags: c++, c, c++11, ncurses

**PROBLEM**

I would like to add persistence to a ncurses program: *write the last displayed screen to disk on exit, read that last displayed screen back from disk on entry*.  If possible, include the background and foreground colors.

**QUESTION**

1. Is there a way to read the entire block of text from ncurses that appears in a NWindow or NPanel or will I have to maintain my own buffer and essentially write/read twice (to my buffer and to ncurses)?
2. Same question for COLOR_PAIR information.

**ANSWER**

[Rici's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17356516/975129) is perfect, but I had to experiment a little to get the call orders right.

**USAGE**

*The code below actually works great for saving and restoring color.*

- Run it once without arguments to write out a screen dump file `/tmp/scr.dump`.
- Run it again with the argument `read` to read from the file.

**CODE**

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <string.h>

void print_in_middle(WINDOW *win, int starty, int startx, int width, char *string);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

   bool read_mode = ( argc>1 && !strcmp( argv[1], "read" ));

   initscr();          /* Start curses mode        */

   if(has_colors() == FALSE)
   {
       endwin();
       printf("Your terminal does not support color\n");
       return 1;
   }
   start_color();              /* Start color          */
   use_default_colors();   // allow for -1 to mean default color
   init_pair(1, COLOR_RED, -1);

   if ( read_mode )
   {
       refresh();
       if ( scr_restore( "/tmp/scr.dump" )!=OK )
       {
           fprintf( stderr, "ERROR DURING RESTORE\n" );
           return 1;
       }
       doupdate();

       attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));
       print_in_middle(stdscr, LINES / 2 + 9, 0, 0, "Read from /tmp/scr.dump" );
       attroff(COLOR_PAIR(1));
   } else {
       attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));
       print_in_middle(stdscr, LINES / 2, 0, 0, "Viola !!! In color ...");
       attroff(COLOR_PAIR(1));

       if ( scr_dump( "/tmp/scr.dump" )!=OK )
       {
           fprintf( stderr, "ERROR WHILE DUMPING" );
           return 1;
       }
   }

  getch();
   endwin();
}

void print_in_middle(WINDOW *win, int starty, int startx, int width, char *string)
{  int length, x, y;
   float temp;

   if(win == NULL)
       win = stdscr;
   getyx(win, y, x);
   if(startx != 0)
       x = startx;
   if(starty != 0)
       y = starty;
   if(width == 0)
       width = 80;

   length = strlen(string);
   temp = (width - length)/ 2;
   x = startx + (int)temp;
   mvwprintw(win, y, x, "%s", string);
   refresh();
}
```

Comment: Why not just store enough to rebuild the screen from your app logic?

Comment: @crowder I did mention that as an option in my OP (under Q1.) - I am trying to avoid it if possible (after all, ncurses has all that information somewhere stored in memory already!)  Also note that storing my own buffer is essentially a rewrite of the ncurses front-end without actually writing to screen.

Comment: Sure, but the amount of information you'll have to store is potentially far less, and you'll have to rebuild some context to figure out what state your app is in on restore, anyway. For example, a "less" style app would only need to store a file offset. Better still, your custom stored info wouldn't be invalidated by a screen size change, as ncurses "state" would.

Comment: @crowder I try to write as little new code as possible as I'm allergic to bugs - but nm, looks like rici below has a good solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `man scr_dump`:

```
   scr_dump, scr_restore, scr_init, scr_set -
       read (write) a curses screen from (to) a file
```

Comment: this solution is perfect - I have added code to the OP for others who may find it useful